# How to know an Index's ElasticSearch version on Disk?

Tags: elasticsearch, migration

How can someone know the ElasticSearch version of an Index on disk?  I have a case where I'd like to know what version of ElasticSearch an index was created with so that I can perform some additional steps before taking on migration of the index to a newer ES version.  Like perhaps explain to a user on upgrade -- "Hey, this might take a while, need to migrate your index."  The assumption here is that ES is shutdown at this point and I cannot directly get the ES version from ElasticSearch.  Additionally, there may be more than one index and therefor more than one version for that set of indexes... (not sure why that would be the case, but better to expect the worst).

Based on the Index data on disk, how can someone tell the version of ElasticSearch which produced that Index?

Comment: You can briefly start ES with `bin/elasticsearch -V` to just print out the version and exit.

Comment: Doesn't that just output the version of the elasticsearch binary -- not the version of the index either created by that ES bin or some other ES bin?

Comment: If you know the ES version, you know with which other version that is compatible with or not. That's sufficient, unless you want to open that index with Lucene directly, which I seriously doubt.